# expo bare app crash after 'expo-splash-screen-command' command

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I recently ejected my react native app using expo to bare workflow. As it seems we should use expo-splash-screen for splash loading screen. after I used "expo-splash-screen-command" as below the iOS app crashes and doesn't open without any error and on the android app the splash screen doesn't fade away.
I used expo sdk 37.

```
npx expo-splash-screen -r "cover" -p "all" "#0a0234" ~/assets/images/splash.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

And then run `yarn`.